# How could I see that $X$ is a countable union of compact sets, and hence it is lindelof?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Here is an answer from somebody who kindly help me to answer one question.

1) Let $Z$ be the Alexandroff duplicate of the Cantor space. All that matters here is that $Z$ is compact, zero-dimensional, first countable and $d(Z)=\mathfrak{c}$, where $d(\cdot)$ stands for density (i.e. least size of a dense subspace).

2) Let $Y=Z^\omega$ with the product topology. Then $Y$ is also homogeneous

3) Fix $p \in Y$ and let $X=Y \setminus \{p\}$.

Since $Y$ is compact homogeneous, $p$ is not isolated in $Y$ and therefore $X$ is not compact; however $X$ is Lindelof, being a countable union of compact sets.

**How could I see that $X$ is a countable union of compact sets, and hence it is lindelof?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from $Y$ being first countable (a countable product of first countable spaces is first countable).  Pick a countable local basis around $p$, let say, $\{V_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. It follows, from definition of local basis, that $\{p\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n$. Hence, $Y\setminus\{p\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (Y \setminus V_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for each $z\in Z$, $Z\setminus\{z\}$ is an $F_\sigma$ set in $Z$. Let $p=\langle p_k:k\in\omega\rangle$. For $k\in\omega$ let $Z\setminus\{p_k\}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}F_k(n)$, where each $F_k(n)$ is closed in $Z$ and therefore compact. For $k,n\in\omega$ let $Y(k,n)=\{y\in Y:y_k\in F_n\}$; then $X=\bigcup_{k,n\in\omega}Y(k,n)$, and each $Y(k,n)$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks Brain. But How could I see that $Y(k,n)$ is compact?

Comment: @Paul: It’s a product of of compact spaces, $F_k(n)$ and $\omega$ copies of the compact space $Z$. Let $A_m=Z$ if $m\ne k$ and $A_k=F_k(n)$; then $Y(k,n)=\prod_{m\in\omega}A_m$.

Comment: From the answer of azarel, the fact that $Y$ is a countable union of compact sets does not matter with the space $Z$. Is it right?

Comment: @Paul: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Both proofs use the fact that $Y$ is a countable product of first countable compact Hausdorff spaces, and both show that that’s all you need, so the other information about $Z$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome.